# Why does dangerouslySetInnerHTML on a script not execute?

Tags: reactjs

I'm at a loss! On React 18.3:

```
function ScriptTest() {
  const __html = `console.log('EXEC')`;

  return (
    <script
      suppressHydrationWarning
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html }}
    />
  );
}
```

You will never see the console.log() in React. Why / how is this different than:

```
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerHTML = 'console.log("EXEC")';
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

Note: I am aware that the HTML5 spec does not allow executing a `<script>` tag inserted via innerHTML. But this is not that situation.

Searching through the source, is it possible that React is actually using `.textContent`?

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1293047d6063f3508af15e68cca916660ded791e/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/client/ReactFiberConfigDOM.js#L556-L558

EDIT: it seems that .textContent will also execute, so that is likely not the issue:

```
const s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = 'console.log("EXEC")';
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

Comment: While it is likely that React is using `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`, the code is executed in both cases, so the problem won't be there.

Comment: Injecting the whole `<script>` tag using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` also does not help. The problem likely lies in React not using `appendChild` but some other mechanism to render the HTML, where the browser does not pick up that `script` tag was added.

Comment: Anyway, if you want the code to be executed, can you just call `eval` on it? (It's just as unsafe, but won't require HTML trickery)

Comment: "Injecting the whole <script> tag using dangerouslySetInnerHTML...":

As I said, @ŠimonKocúrek, executing a `<script>` via innerHTML is not permitted by the HTML 5 spec.